# import excel,openoffice and ms office 2007 data to db in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel-2007, spreadsheet, import-from-excel

I found many have suggested spreadsheet gem in rails for reading excel sheet which is not working with ms office 2007 file(xlsx). And i am not sure it do work for open office file.

so i wish to know will it work for openoffice or any other gem will support all the spreadsheet format.
Its really lot of similar questions here but no great answers for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) will handle all the spreadsheet formats. But before instaling roo, you will have to install 'nokogiri', 'google-spreadsheet-ruby', 'builder' gems.